# How to print jQuery datatable in landscap mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, landscape

I am trying to print datatable in landscape mode, here is my code which i am using:

```
var table = jQuery('#dyntable_client_orders').DataTable({
    lengthChange: true,
    //responsive: false,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis',{
            extend: 'print',
            customize: function ( win ) {
                console.log(win.styleMedia.type);
                win.styleMedia.type = 'print';

            }
        }]
});
```

I also tried this:

```
var table = jQuery('#dyntable_client_orders').DataTable({
    lengthChange: true,
    //responsive: false,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis',{
            extend: 'print',
            orientation: 'landscape'
        }]
});
```

Comment: Well? any attempt? did you try `orientation: 'landscape'` ?

Comment: @pedram yes i tried it, you can see above code

Comment: @Pedram orientation: 'landscape' works only in pdf check this link https://datatables.net/reference/button/print#Options

Answer (score 0):

To 'print' landscape, you have to include it in exportOptions.  I made the same mistake.

```
{
 extend: 'print',
  exportOptions: {
    orientation: 'landscape'
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
var table = jQuery('#dyntable_client_orders').DataTable({
    lengthChange: true,
    //responsive: false,
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'colvis',{
     extend: 'pdfHtml5',
     orientation: 'landscape',
     pageSize: 'LEGAL' }]
});
```

Comment: 'pdfHtml5' is for pdf, i want for 'print'